# AngularJS filtering doesn't work

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects like this:

[image]

In HTML i wrote:

```
    <input ng-model="search.modelName" />

    <div class="market-slot col-xs-5 col-xm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" ng-show="item.model != false">
```

When i typing some in input, it doesn't apply to filter...

UPD:

Input from JSON got by the $http.post

Output looks like this:
[image]

You can see I was type "Manana" in input, so only objects who has "modelName == Manana" should be shown.

Comment: Please provide inputs and expected/actual outputs of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Stated in the example of ng docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

The following should work

```
<input ng-model="searchText" />
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchText" ng-if="item.model != false">
```

There are more examples in the docs where you can define how strict and by which key in the model you'd want to search

following statements could apply on your app:

- `search.$` (filter through any applicable key in the model)
- `search.modelName` (filter through the **modelName** key, if declared, in the model)

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample for you here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fobvRnzotzHHdRY12hZU?p=preview)

HTML Source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.modelName" />
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" ng-show="item.model != false">
    <pre>
      {{item}}
    </pre>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript script.js Code

```
angular.module('App',[])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.items = [
  {
    model : true,
    modelName : 'FirstModel',
    owner : 'Owner1'

  },
  {
    model : true,
    modelName : 'SecondModel',
    owner : 'Owner2'

  },
  {
    model : false,
    modelName : 'ThirdModel',
    owner : 'Owner3'        
  }
];
});
```